# How to fix supply a layout_width attribute in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my application i want use `RelativeLayout` and for set **size** to this i use `dimens` .
**I write my XML code such as below :**

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/listItemAuction_productImgLay"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size120New"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding5"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            </RelativeLayout>
```

**Dimen size :**     `<dimen name="size120New">120</dimen>`

But when run application show me below **error** on `Logcat` :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #26: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

How can i fix it and us `dimes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your width dimenension needs a unit

120 on its own is meaningless. You probably wanted 120dp. A dp is a unit of physical measurement, independent of resolution and this is how android maintains compatiblity with different devices.

EG:

```
<dimen name="size120New">120dp</dimen>
```

There are also other units, this answer explains well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/2762277

Comment: Oh oh, yesss. i forget write **`dp`** . thanks dear friend